# Copy, modify the copied content and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I’m facing a little challenge where I am trying to achieve a copy/paste of data from one column to another while slightly altering the original structure.
This should be done in the whole column range (e.g. B:B or C:C) as Macro to run prior to bigger script manipulating these cells further. I have everything completed, but struggling with this part.

[image]

I have posted this question at [this forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/copy-data-and-paste-them-in-slightly-different-structure.1133540/#post-5483134) but no success (Just wanted to mention the above to make sure I don't waste anybody's time)

Comment: Please post pictures and code directly here at SO. External sources are not reliable over time

Comment: I doubt you will be able to use the Excel object model to manipulate data on the clipboard.  What you could do is create a hidden workbook or "very hidden" worksheet, paste the data there, manipulate it then copy/paste it to the target range.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by looping the rows in VBA, removing any old data from columns A and B, and then using some string manipulation to add in the data from columns C and D. Something like this should get you started:

```
Sub sAddData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim aInData() As String
    Dim aOutData() As String
    Dim strData As String
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngLoop1 = 2 To lngLastRow
'   deal with adding info from column D to column A
        aOutData() = Split(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1), ";")
        strData = ""
        For lngLoop2 = LBound(aOutData) To UBound(aOutData)
            If Left(aOutData(lngLoop2), 3) <> "ADD" Then strData = strData & aOutData(lngLoop2) & ";"
        Next lngLoop2
        aInData() = Split(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 4), ";")
        For lngLoop2 = LBound(aInData) To UBound(aInData)
            Select Case Left(aInData(lngLoop2), 4)
                Case "{S1}", "{S6}", "{S10"
                    strData = strData & Mid(aInData(lngLoop2), InStr(aInData(lngLoop2), "}") + 1) & ";"
            End Select
        Next lngLoop2
        If Right(strData, 1) = ";" Then strData = Left(strData, Len(strData) - 1)
        ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1) = strData

'   deal with adding info from column C to column B
        strData = ""
        strData = ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 2)
        If Left(strData, 4) = "[NUM" Then strData = Mid(strData, InStr(strData, ".") + 2)
        If Len(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 3)) > 0 Then
            strData = "[NUM - " & Replace(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 3), "*", ", ") & "]. " & strData
        End If
        ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 2) = strData
    Next lngLoop1
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sAddData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH guys! will test it asap and ask away - should I need any further help! Keep well!